# How to enable widget / Broadcast Receiver by code that is disabled on the Manifest?

Tags: android, android-widget, broadcastreceiver

I have read many questions and tried without any success but it seems to be impossible to activate an widget/brodcast receiver that is disabled on the manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".widget.WidgetProvider"
        android:enabled="false">
 ....
    </receiver>
```

Using this code doesnt work:

```
    ComponentName component = new ComponentName(this, WidgetProvider.class);
    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(
            component,
            PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
            PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

I read in my places that it should work but it doesnt!

I have even trying testing the component state:

```
    int nComponentEnabledState = pm.getComponentEnabledSetting(component);
    Log.i("Widget", "Widget Component State: " + nComponentEnabledState);
```

Which return 1 which means it is active but the widget doesn't appear on the widget list which is driving me crazy! What am i doing wrong?

Comment: "What am i doing wrong?" -- you are assuming that all home screens are going to detect the fact that you enabled this component and will reload their list of available app widgets. Try rebooting the device or emulator, after executing your code, and see if your app widget becomes available.

Comment: Hi there i already tried that but it still doesnt work! The funny thing is doing the opposite (enable on the manifest and then disable/enabled by code) works without a problem!

Comment: Hmmm... I know that enabling/disabling receivers in general works fine, or at least it did when I last tried it. There may be some sort of database of app widgets that is not getting updated in this case. You might want to try your code on a couple of different environments (e.g., emulator plus hardware) to see if the results vary.

Comment: I already tried on kitkat emulator, nexus 5 running Android 6, Samsung tablet running Cyanogen Android 5.1.1 nothing works! I dont want the user to be able to see the Widget before running the app! The widget is  supposed to be part of my IAP any other way to do this?

Comment: Off the cuff, I do not have any suggestions -- sorry!

Comment: Okay thanks for your help! I should report this to Google since reading: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED supports the assumption that it should work!